# unable to add price sets?

Tags: price-sets

[image]I am trying to set up registration for an event that requires price sets. When I press Price Set I'm unable to add any. Has anyone else experienced this? Is there something I need to do first?

here's all I see:

Comment: have you compared to how things work on one of the civicrm demo sites

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean exactly, but I'm unable to access any of the steps (see photo posted above). thanks!

Comment: i am trying to help you unpack whether the issue is with civicrm, or your install. so using one of the Demo sites eg http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ gives you a benchmark

Answer (score 1):

That's CiviCRM 4.1.6 - it's unlikely you'll find anyone here who can help you with that version.

It's possible that upgrading to 4.6 or 4.7 itself will solve the issue - lots has changed since. And if any issues remain you'll be on a version that's currently supported by the community.

Answer (score 0):

When you do 'manage price sets' or 'new price set' you see NO input text boxes, where you can enter the price-set name?  I can't see your URL but presumably you'd see the textboxes to allow you to input the name, financial type, etc.
Can you verify your user permissions? (presumably you're an admin).